# Find Subset Combination in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I have difficulties with this particular problem.

I was asked to find a combination subsets that have strictly one element less than the input array. For example from array:

```
var num = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Find these combinations:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[2,3,4,5]
[1,2,4,5]
[1,2,3,5]
[1,3,4,5]
```

and from this array:

```
var num = [2,4,6]
```

Find these combinations:

```
[2,4]
[2,6]
[4,6]
```

I already tried this code but it is not dynamic since I must print every index of the array:

```
var num = [1,2,3,4,5];
var n = num.length;
var i, j;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
        console.log(num[i] + ", " +  num[j]);
    }
}
```

Are there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not well-defined, do you mean to find all subsets that have strictly one element less than the input array ?

Comment: Are there ever duplicates in the array and if so how should that be handled?

Comment: @UriGoren Yes, thank you for the correction, I already revised the question

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, the first set contain [2,3,4,5], already listed in the question

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the unique combination is only limited to the particular index in the array. The value could be duplicate for that matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are just removing one element for each result, you will have a result for every element in your original list. You can just `map()` and `slice()`:

```js
const remove = (num) => num.map((_, i, arr) => [...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i+1)])

console.log(remove([1,2,3,4,5]))
console.log(remove([2, 4, 6]))
```

Comment: what about having an array of five elements and a result set with three elements?

Comment: @NinaScholz - that wouldn't fit the problem which specifically says, "subsets that have strictly one element less than the input array."

Comment: @NinaScholz -- yeah, the title is a little misleading.

Comment: @MarkMeyer My apology for the ambiguity of the thread title, already edited it. Hope it helps.Also thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a generator and take only one element or the result.

```js
function* getCombinations(array, length, left = []) {
    var i = 0;
    if (!length) yield left;
    while (i < array.length) {
        yield* getCombinations(array.slice(i + 1), length - 1, [...left, array[i]]);
        i++;
    }
}

console.log([...getCombinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)].map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log([...getCombinations([2, 4, 6], 2)].map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log([...getCombinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)].map(a => a.join(' ')));  // not asked
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For deleting only one element you could filter the array.

```js
function* getCombinations(array) {
    var l = array.length;
    while (l--) yield array.filter((_, i) => i !== l);
}

console.log([...getCombinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)].map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log([...getCombinations([2, 4, 6], 2)].map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do something Like:**

> Loop the array and remove one each time

```js
// Function to return an array except the given one
Array.prototype.except = function(val) {
    return this.filter(function(x) { return x !== val; });        
}; 


// For array of 5
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
var result1 = []

array1.forEach(function(val){
  result1.push(array1.except(val))
});

console.log('For Array of 5')
console.log(result1)


// For array of 3

var num = [2,4,6]
var num_result = []
num.forEach(function(val){
  num_result.push(num.except(val))
});
console.log('For Array of 3')
console.log(num_result)
```